# how can set auto width for columns parent and remove columns-gap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, multiple-columns, column-count

I have **2** **`div`** **inline**, one of the `div` (right side) should take up `30% width` and the other `div`(left side) should take auto width.

The page I am making is a horizontal scrolling page. And I have used `ul` `li` in the `div`(left side) and I want `li` to be in the form of a `column`, so I have set `column-count` with `jquery` or `javascript` to `set new column` automatically when I added new li the `column-gap` is set `0` to remove the space between them.

In fact, I want the `columns` to stick together perfectly and `li` should have **, For Example,** `300px width` and when I add a new `li` it should add automatically new `column` and increase the `width` of the `div` (left side)

**But I don't know, how to do this?**

**html :**

```
    <main>
        <div class = "right"></div>
        <div class = "left">
           <ul id = "homePage_content-ul">
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </main>
```

**css :**

```
.right{
  width: 30%;
}
.left{
  ... //width must be auto
}
```

**javascript** or jquery

```
var ul = document.getElementById("homePage_content-ul");
var li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
var numItems = li.length;

var css = document.createElement("style");
css.type = "text/css";
css.innerHTML = "ul#homePage_content-ul { column-count: " + Math.round(numItems/2) + "; column-gap: 0; }";
document.body.appendChild(css);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this on parent element

```
display: flex;
```